# Microdata for organization

Tags: html, schema

I'm trying to do the right mikrodaty layout for the site. Do I understand how to act . For example I go to https://schema.org/Organization and go through the list to the bottom . Opt for each tag (name, adress, streetAddress and so on ) . If possible, I need to fill out all the tags , am I right?Now I got something like this:

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
 <div class="historyb" id="historyb">
    <span class="historyh2" itemprop="name">MyName</span>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">
      Street & number of house
    </span>
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">City</span>,
    <span itemprop="postalCode">111111</span>
</div>
  <a href="mailto:MyEmail@gmail.com" itemprop="email">
    MyEmail@gmail.com
   </a>
   <span itemprop="foundingDate">Date</span>
   <span itemprop="foundingLocation">City</span>
   <span itemprop="legalName">Full Name</span>
     <a itemprop="url" href="#"><img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.mysite.ru/images/logo.png" /></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is valid according to [Google's test tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) but you might want to include **addressCountry** and **addressRegion** for https://schema.org/Place